# How to use Joi to validate as subset of a defined list

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I have a query parameter "attributes" who's value should be a subset of a defined list. How would I validate that  with Joi.

For example with a valid list of [a,b] :

```
host/url?attributes=a,b,c # not valid
host/url?attributes=a,b # valid
host/url?attributes=a # valid
host/url?attributes=b # valid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you're looking for. Using [joi.array().items()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayitemstype) & [joi.string().valid()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidvalue---aliases-only-equal). But also not sure what "a" and "b" are supposed to be? Are they strings?

```
const joi = require('joi');

const attributesSchmea = joi.array().items(joi.string().valid(['a', 'b']));

console.log(joi.validate(['a'], attributesSchmea)); // valid
console.log(joi.validate(['a', 'b'], attributesSchmea)); // valid
console.log(joi.validate(['a', 'b', 'c'], attributesSchmea)); // not valid
console.log(joi.validate(['b'], attributesSchmea)); // valid
```